# Can you check my proof on Showing a map on $\mathbb{R}$ is linear using continuity

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, show that $f$ is linear.

Here is my approach: Let $\lambda $ be a scalar, and let $\lambda f(x)=y\in \mathbb{R}$, then there exists $x^\prime\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x^\prime)=y$. Let $\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ such that $|\lambda x-x^\prime|<\delta$ we have $|f(\lambda x)-y|=|f(\lambda)-\lambda f(x)|<\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we can conclude that $\lambda f(x)=f(\lambda x)$.

I haven't use one of the given facts, so I am not sure where it went wrong. Thanks for the helps!

Comment: How did you prove that $[\forall \lambda\in\Bbb R,\forall x\in\Bbb R, \exists x'\in\Bbb R, f(x')=\lambda f(x)]$ ?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thanks! I think I need to prove the function is a bijection then that statement follows?

Comment: With the axiom of choice there are discontinuous additive bijections $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ (which are obviously non-$\Bbb R$-linear) and I don't really follow the part of the answer that comes after the mistake I've mentioned.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I think I wanted to use the definition of continuity of $f$ to show that $\lambda f(x)=f(\lambda x)$

Comment: Well, it's your goal, so you'd better want that. I don't think you've been successful in that regard.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thanks! do you think you can give any suggestions? I'm kind of stuck here for a while now.

Comment: Start by proving that $f(kx) = kf(x)$ for integer $k$. Then show that $f(x/k) = f(x)/k$. Then show $f(rx) = rf(x)$ for rational $r$. Only then will continuity become helpful.

Comment: Please note that the definition of continuity at $x'$ says that $\delta$ can be chosen so that ***IF*** $|\lambda x- x'| < \delta$, ***THEN*** $|f(\lambda x) - f(x')| < \epsilon$. It most certainly does not say that any values of $\lambda x$ and $x'$ you happen to choose will somehow just have a difference $< \delta$.